# C programming, error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors, function-pointers

I am trying to write a program which implements the Pop and Push functions. The problem is, I am trying to pass the pointer that points to integer Top to the function, so that this integer keeps changing, but when I try to compile I always get this line:

> **error: called object is not a function or function pointer (*t)--

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10
int push(int stac[], int *v, int *t)
{
  if((*t) == MAX-1)
  {
      return(0);
  }
  else
  {
      (*t)++;
      stac[*t] = *v;
      return *v;
   }
}

int pop(int stac[], int *t)
{
 int popped;
 if((*t) == -1)
 {
      return(0);
 }
 else
 {
     popped = stac[*t]
     (*t)--;
     return popped;
 } 
}
int main()
{
int stack[MAX];
int value;
int choice;
int decision;
int top;
top = -1;
do{
   printf("Enter 1 to push the value\n");
   printf("Enter 2 to pop the value\n");
   printf("Enter 3 to exit\n");
   scanf("%d", &choice);
   if(choice == 1)
   {
       printf("Enter the value to be pushed\n");
       scanf("%d", &value);
       decision = push(stack, &value, &top);
       if(decision == 0)
       { 
           printf("Sorry, but the stack is full\n");  
       }
       else
       {
           printf("The value which is pushed is: %d\n", decision);
       }
   }
   else if(choice == 2)
    {
         decision = pop(stack, &top);
        if(decision == 0)
          {
               printf("The stack is empty\n");
          }
         else
          {
              printf("The value which is popped is: %d\n", decision);
          }

    }
 }while(choice != 3);
 printf("Top is %d\n", top);

}
```

Answer (score 21):

You missed one semicolon just before that line with error:

```
 poped = stac[*t] <----- here
 (*t)--;
```

The reason for this strange error is that compiler saw sth like that:

```
 poped = stac[*t](*t)--;
```

Which it could interpret as a call to a function pointer coming from a table, but this obviously makes no sense, because stac is an array of ints, not an array of function pointers.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for the mistake and I can't believe that I didn't see the missed semicolon.

Comment: @AbylIkhsanov - that's how life is with these compilers (; That's a good lesson - you frequently need to look for the error BEFORE the line mentioned in the message.